# Use cast in order by clause JPQL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL query in which I want to use cast operator in the order by clause. The query works in SQL but the application gives the shown error at runtime. How to use cast in orderby clause in JPQL query? Thanks in advance.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a where a.tableB.ID = :ID ORDER BY cast(col as unsigned)")
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : unsigned : unsigned [SELECT r FROM classname a where a.tableB.ID = :ID ORDER BY CAST(col as unsigned)]
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast the column to another type for sorting?

Comment: I want to sort string as number to get the records as 1,2,3 instead of 1,10..

Comment: My point is, if you need a column to be interpreted as a number, then perhaps the column shouldn't be of textual type in the first place. Using correct data types is also part of the data validation, because a `VARCHAR` will accept much more than just digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think unsigned is not supported. `interger` might be the closest.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a where a.tableB.ID = :ID ORDER BY cast(col as integer)")
```